# Elasticsearch 6 Mapping creation throwing error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES-6 and the `candidateCreationTime` by default is indexed as number in Kibana. How do i map it to a Date value?

```
{
    "_index": "candidatesources",
    "_type": "candidatesource",
    "_id": "5c08b8930bcfe318ca2a00f4",
    "_version": 3,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "candidateNotes": "Some Notes",
        "candidateCreationTime": 1544066189124,
        "state": "verified"
    }
}
```

I tried it with

```
PUT candidatesources/_mapping/csdate
{
  "properties": {
  "candidateCreationTime": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

But it is giving following error

```
Rejecting mapping update to [candidatesources] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [candidatesource, csdate]
```

How do i make it `date` and not `number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 6.x you can have only one mapping type. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html). Also, as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) mapping for existing fields cannot be updated. So, in your case, you need to create a new index with correct mapping and reindex your data to the new index OR you can add a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to the existing field `candidateCreationTime`mapped as a `date` field.